# How to set [disabled] attr when reaching horizontal scroll end? (Tiny-Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [Tiny-Slider 2](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider) and stumbled upon this bug: the `next` button does not get the `[disabled]` attribute when the last slide is displayed. Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/1818/pen/BaaePaL). 
 To reproduce the problem, click on the `next` button until the slider stops moving the slides, and you will see that the `next` button does not have the `[disabled]` attribute. The `next` button will get the `[disabled]` attribute only after a few more clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiny-slider version: 2.9.1
Create your own buttons (arrows) prev and next, assign them identifiers, the code based on the width of the container and the width of the blocks will set the parameter disabled = true|false.
Example https://codepen.io/cvaize/pen/zYYVRGo

```js
const prev = document.getElementById('road-map-prev')
const next = document.getElementById('road-map-next')

const roadMap = tns({
  container: "#road-map",
  gutter: 43,
  autoWidth: true,
  mouseDrag: false,
  loop: false,
  nav: false
});


prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!prev.disabled){
    roadMap.goTo('prev')
  }
})
next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!next.disabled){
    roadMap.goTo('next')
  }
})
roadMap.events.on('indexChanged', (v) => {
  const item = document.querySelectorAll('#road-map .tns-item')
  const roadMapIW = document.getElementById('road-map-iw')
  let index = v.displayIndex - 1
  let fullWidth = 0
  let offsetWidth = 0
  item.forEach((value, index2) => {
    fullWidth += value.offsetWidth
    if(index2 < index){
      offsetWidth = fullWidth
    }
  })
  prev.disabled = (index === 0)
  next.disabled = (fullWidth - offsetWidth < roadMapIW.offsetWidth)
});
```

```css
.tns-controls{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/tiny-slider.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="road-map overflow-hidden">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Road map SO</h2>
          <div class="road-map-controls" aria-label="Carousel Navigation" tabindex="0">
            <button id="road-map-prev" data-controls="prev" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="road-map" disabled>prev</button>
            <button id="road-map-next" data-controls="next" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="road-map">next</button>
          </div>
          <div id="road-map">
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 ноября</div>
              Формирование идеи, <br />исследование рынка
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 декабря</div>
              Создание команды
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 января</div>
              Презентация проекта <br />на тематических <br />сайтах и форумах
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">4 февраля</div>
              Начало баунти <br />программы
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">2 марта</div>
              Pre-sale
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 ноября</div>
              Формирование идеи, <br />исследование рынка
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 декабря</div>
              Создание команды
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 января</div>
              Презентация проекта <br />на тематических <br />сайтах и форумах
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">4 февраля</div>
              Начало баунти <br />программы
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">2 марта</div>
              Pre-sale
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 ноября</div>
              Формирование идеи, <br />исследование рынка
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 декабря</div>
              Создание команды
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">1 января</div>
              Презентация проекта <br />на тематических <br />сайтах и форумах
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">4 февраля</div>
              Начало баунти <br />программы
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="text-primary">2 марта</div>
              Pre-sale
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```